# Why isn't my toString method working in Java?

Tags: java, tostring

I'm in the process of writing a news feed program, and I'm trying to check if items are being added to the list array properly. In my test harness, I try to print the contents of the array after adding a made up item, but when I run the program, nothing is displayed. Is there a problem with my toString method (or otherwise)? Thanks for any help.

```
public class Feed {

private final int DEFAULT_MAX_ITEMS = 10;   // default size of array

/* Attribute declarations */
private String name;        // the name of the feed
private String[] list;      // the array of items
private int size;           // the amount of items in the feed

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Feed(String name){
    list = new String[DEFAULT_MAX_ITEMS];
    size = 0;
}

/**
 * add method adds an item to the list
 * @param item
 */
public void add(String item){
    item = new String();

    // add it to the array of items
            // if array is not big enough, double its capacity automatically
            if (size == list.length)
                expandCapacity();

    // add reference to item at first free spot in array
            list[size] = item;
            size++; 
    }

/**
 * expandCapacity method is a helper method
 * that creates a new array to store items with twice the capacity
 * of the existing one
 */
private void expandCapacity(){
    String[] largerList = new String[list.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        largerList[i] = list[i];

    list = largerList;
}


/**
 * toString method returns a string representation of all items in the list
 * @return 
 */
public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        s = s + list[i].toString()+ "\n";
    }
    return s;
}

/**
 * test harness
 */

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Feed testFeed = new Feed("test");
    testFeed.add("blah blah blah");
    System.out.println(testFeed.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: `public void add(String item){
    item = new String();` Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: You're overwriting your `String` value in `add`.

Comment: Are you bound to use `String[]`? If you can use `ArrayList<String>` you don't need to worry about expanding the array when it reaches max size.

Comment: I think my problem lies in my add method, as some of you have stated (and FYI I am bound to use String[]). How can I add a String item that is a parameter into an array? This is the critical bit of code:
`public void add(String item){
  item = new String();` Do I have to use `this` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here.  For starters, I'd suggest:

1) Lose the "size" member variable

2) Substitute `ArrayList<String> list` for member variable "String[] list"

3) Use `list.size()` instead of a separate "size" variable

4) You can lose (or simplify) your "add()" method, too.  Just use `list.add()` instead.

5) Step through the debugger.  Verify "list" gets added to as you expect, when you expect.

FINALLY

6) Step through the debugger for "toString()".  Make sure "list" is has the size and contents you expect.

'Hope that helps...